# How can I set default editor to vim for the open command on mac?

Tags: macos

I am aware that I should put the following in my `.bash_profile` and my `.zshrc`:

```bash
export EDITOR=vim
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

I have also ran `source .bash_profile` and `source .zshrc` respectively (trying it both ways).

However, when I run the `open` command on my terminal to open a file, it still brings me to Mac's text editor. How do I make it go to vim?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a function or script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

editfile(){
    osascript - vim "$@" <<EOF
on run argv
    set argList to {}
    repeat with arg in argv
        set end of argList to quoted form of arg
    end repeat
    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, space}
    set argList to argList as text
    set text item delimiters to TID

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script argList & "; exit"
    end tell
end run
EOF
}

editfile /etc/hosts
```